# C++ this pointer, hidden argument in function calls

Tags: c++, this

I have a stack class with members and a function called push.

```
class STACK
{
    int data;
    public:
    void push(int x)
    {
        data=x;
    }
}
```

What does C++ do to convert this statement:

```
s1.push(3);
```

to

```
s1.push(this,3);
```

Basically my question is what happens under the hood to generate the `this` pointer and pass it as a hidden argument?

I am actually coding in C. My objective is to have a program which is as close to OOP as possible. For this i have function pointers as members of the structure. Therefore, I want to know if it is possible to somehow have track of which structure called the function (like a "this" pointer ). I don't want to do something like: s1.push(&s1,3); because it beats my purpose.

**IS IT possible to convert s1.push(3); to s1.push(&1,3); via MACRO substitution**

Answer (score 8):

First things first! The statement:

```
s1.push(3);
```

is NOT translated to:

```
 s1.push(this, 3);
```

But to something like this:

```
STACK::push(&s1, 3);
```

Where `STACK::push` may be treated as global/namespace or static function under class/namespace `STACK`, whose prototype would be:

```
push(STACK const* pThis, int arg);
```

The `this` pointer is always the first argument to the method (function). If method has zero argument, it will still have one argument (the `this` pointer of class).

Comment: is it possible to achieve this via coding?? (i mean explicitly converting to push(STACK const* pThis, int arg); )

Comment: The obvious question is WHY. Why do you want to do that? May be you could write a global or static function and pass pointer of class.

Comment: I am actually coding in C. My objective is to have a program which is as close to OOP as possible. For this i have function pointers as members of the structure. Therefore, I want to know if it is possible to somehow have track of which structure called the function (like a "this" pointer ). I dont want to do something like:  s1.push(&s1,3); because it beats my purpose.

Comment: Well, you're out of luck. C does not have great facilities for OO programming. You *need* to explicitly pass the address of the object that your function is supposed to work on.

Comment: IS IT possible to convert s1.push(3); to s1.push(&1,3); via MACRO substitution

Comment: Macro cannot have dot within it. Otherwise, yes, you can have macro like `#define STACKPUSH(object, argument) ((object).push(argument))`

Comment: it would not be `STACK const* pThis`. It would be `STACK *const  pThis`

Comment: @Ajay `STACK::push(&s1, 3); ` [does not compile](https://godbolt.org/z/cqb4eTPjb). What do you think about it?

Comment: @John That's just logical representation what compiles does. You should see the assembly generated with original code and see how `this` is pushed to stack.

Answer (score 3):

There is no magic

```
s1.push(3);
```

is just syntax for

```
STACK::push(&s1, 3);
```

Comment: Well, the "magic" here is that `push(...)` becomes a plain (i.e. C-type) function with an additional `STACK*` parameter. To avoid name clashes with other plain functions, internally the name is "mangled" to include the class name as well among other things.

Comment: ...and things get a bit more complicated when methods become virtual ;)

Comment: The question was about the magic of this, and there is no magic for this, it's just the address of the object used. I do know about the *magic* of making STACK::push do the right thing.

Comment: IS IT possible to convert s1.push(3); to s1.push(&1,3); via MACRO substitution

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean by MACRO substition, but in a limited sense you can do something simmilar. See [C with Pseudo-Classes](https://sites.google.com/site/rcorcs/posts/cwithpseudo-classes).

Comment: @Thomas `STACK::push(&s1, 3); ` [does not compile](https://godbolt.org/z/cqb4eTPjb). What do you think about it?

Comment: well, you need to get a [pointers to member function](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/pointer#Pointers_to_member_functions), and that gets called with a different syntax, see [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f7a19034938ecc15)

Answer (score 0):

```
this = &s1
```

The address of s1 is known, so it can be passed to STACK::push. It's that simple :)

Comment: i totally agree. But the line of code is s1.push(3); 
how does it become s1.push(this,3);

Comment: Man, compiler is not a hello world program.
"But the line of code is s1.push(3)" is not an argument. Compiler does a lot much more difficult tasks than passing hidden parameters.

Comment: @DarshanShah: in the same way that the code `int main(){}` turns into an executable file in your file system: because that's what the compiler *does*.

Answer (score 0):

C++ does not exactly convert statements (because C++ is a language specification, and you could implement that language in many ways, even -unethically- with a population of slaves working on paper; you don't need a computer, even if you want one, to have C++). The compiler (e.g. GCC) translates the statement to some other lower level representations. With GCC, it is Gimple statements, and the Gimple representation can be examined, e.g. with [MELT's probe](http://gcc-melt.org/index.html#probe_id) or [-fdump-tree-gimple](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Debugging-Options.html) and other options (like `-fdump-tree-all` or `-fdump-tree-ssa` etc...)

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, you have to specify the pointer explicitly or implicitly in C.

For C++, it is the compiler's responsibility to set the implicit `this` pointer as the argument for a class member function. In your code, the member function is mangled as `void STACK::push(STACK*, int)` in compilation automatically by the compiler, then, when the member function `STACK::push` is called, the compiler will set the object address (`this`) as an argument (generally the 1st one) to the member function `STACK::push`.

No C compiler will offer above functions, thus, it's the users responsibility to set the pointer.

Answer (score 0):

After your edit, the question takes up another problem - OOP in C. That's difficult and type-unsafe, but possible to implement. You can look at GObject library, which provides object system in C. I guess it makes heavy use of macros.