# Get the return type of a method from a member function pointer

Tags: c++, type-traits, pointer-to-member, decltype

I'm trying to declare a variable so that its type is the same as the return type of a member function to which I have a member function pointer.

```
class Widget {
    public:
        std::chrono::milliseconds Foo();
};
```

For example, given a member function pointer `fn` which points to `Widget::Foo`, 
how would I declare a variable `blah` so that it gets `Widget::Foo`'s return type (`std::chrono::milliseconds`)?

I found some promising guidance from a blog post that uses `result_of` from `<type_traits>` along with `decltype`, but I can't seem to get it to work.

```
auto fn = &Widget::Foo;
Widget w;
std::result_of<decltype((w.*fn)())>::type blah;
```

This approach makes sense to me, but VC++ 2013 doesn't like it.

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\include\xrefwrap(58): error C2064: term does not evaluate to a function taking 0 arguments
      C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\include\xrefwrap(118) : see reference to class template instantiation 'std::_Result_of<_Fty,>' being compiled
      with
      [
          _Fty=std::chrono::milliseconds (__cdecl Widget::* )(void)
      ]
      scratch.cpp(24) : see reference to class template instantiation 'std::result_of<std::chrono::milliseconds (__cdecl Widget::* (void))(void)>' being compiled
```

I don't know if I'm doing something wrong or if this is something that VC++ doesn't handle yet (or both!).  The only clue I see in the error message is the `__cdecl`.  Shouldn't the calling convention be `__thiscall`?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

```
decltype((w.*fn)()) blah;
```

Or

```
std::result_of<decltype(fn)(Widget)>::type blah;
```

Comment: 1.What about the function named `foo` has parameters?  2. What does `decltype(fn)(Widget)` mean?

Comment: @John That is the 'class member function pointer', and the first parameter is 'this pointer'(ECX register). If multiple argument required, append the type of args after 'Widget'.

Comment: @John for example 'std::result_of_t<decltype(&T::operator[])(T, size_t)>;' for class T has member 'operator[](size_t)'

Comment: Important Note: `result_of` is removed in C++20. Use `invoke_result` instead! https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/result_of

Comment: Also: instead of `std::result_of<>::type` you can use `std::result_of_t<>`. Respectively `std::invoke_result<>::type` -> `std::invoke_result_t<>`

Answer (score 3):

Since C++17 you can use
`std::invoke_result`
like this:

```cpp
std::invoke_result<fn,Widget>::type foo;
```

But a bit nicer is this:

```cpp
std::invoke_result_t<fn,Widget> bar;
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't know why it works with:

```
std::result_of<decltype(fn)(Widget)>::type blah;
```

But I think  in brackets should be a pointer to Widget. Because [the first member parameter is hidden 'this', a pointer to object](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15322286/1433373)

```
std::result_of<decltype(fn)(Widget*)>::type blah;
```

```
class Widget
{
public:
    virtual int foo() = 0;
};

int Widget::foo() { }

int main() {
    // Your code goes here
    auto fn = &Widget::foo;
    std::result_of<decltype(fn)(Widget*)>::type blah = 5;
    std::cout << blah;
    return 0;
}

// output: 5
```

Also we can't create objects of abstract classes, so code won't compile, if Widget will be an abstract class and not its pointer will be in the brackets

```
std::result_of<decltype(fn)(Widget)>::type blah = 5;
```

Compile error:

```
error: cannot declare parameter to be of abstract type 'Widget'
  std::result_of<decltype(fn)(Widget)>::type blah = 5;//

error: incomplete type 'std::result_of<int (Widget::*(Widget))()>' used in    nested name specifier
  std::result_of<decltype(fn)(Widget)>::type blah = 5;//
```