# Retrieve element_type of std::shared_ptr when retrieving the return type of a method

Tags: c++, templates, return-type

I am trying to get the return type of a class method. The return type is a `std::shared_ptr`. From that I am trying to get the `element_type`. I've tried using `std::result_of` of as described in the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29185018/2020804

But so far I was unsuccessful. Here is my example:

```cpp
class A {};
    
class B 
{
    const std::shared_ptr<A> foo() const;
};
    
const auto method = &B::foo;
using result = std::result_of<decltype(method)(B)>::type;  // const std::shared_ptr<A> &
```

I would now like to get the `element_type` of result (aka `A`). I've tried using `decltype(result)::element_type`, but I am getting an `Unexpected type name 'result': expected expression` error. I've also read, that `std::result_of` is deprecated in C++20, so I am wondering what is the correct modern solution to this problem?

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: `result` is a type alias, `decltype` expects an expression (usually just a variable). You wanted `result::element_type`.

Comment: This works for me, it returns `shared_ptr<A>`,


`using result = std::invoke_result<decltype(&B::foo), B>::type;`
`std::cout << typeid(result).name() << std::endl;`

Comment: `std::result_of` is deprecated in c++17 and removed in c++20

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> what is the correct modern solution to this problem?

Since `result_of` is deprecated you should use decltype as shown below:

```
const auto method = &B::foo;
using result = decltype((B().*method)()); 

//now you can get the element_type
using ElementType = result::element_type; // typename decltype((B().*method)())::element_type;
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/zGsTTxcMY)

Note that you can also directly get the `element_type` by writing:

```
using ElementType = typename decltype((B().*method)())::element_type;
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/E71jhYoE5)

---

> but I am getting an Unexpected type name 'result': expected expression error

The **problem** is that `result` is an alias for a type(aka type alias) and the argument of a decltype cannot be a type(or type alias).

To solve this you can directly write `result::element_type`.