# Explicitly passing *this in C++

Tags: c++, class, object, this, member-functions

While reading about [`*this`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/this-pointer?view=vs-2019), I saw:

> When a nonstatic member function is called for an object, the compiler
>   passes the object's address to the function as a hidden argument.

Then I tried:

```
#include <iostream>

class MyClass
{
    int myVar;
public:
    MyClass(const int& val) : myVar{val} {}
    // int getVar(MyClass* this) <-- Error: expected ',' or '...' before 'this'
    int getVar()
    {
        return this->myVar;
    }
};

int main()
{
    MyClass obj(22);
    // std::cout << obj.getVar(&obj);      <-- Error: no matching function
    // std::cout << MyClass::getVar(&obj); <-- Error: no matching function
    std::cout << obj.getVar();
    return 0;
}
```

Why am I not able to access the hidden argument? Is it called 'hidden' because of that?

Are only compilers allowed to do this? Can't we explicitly mention `*this` in the function signature?

The closest answer I've found before asking this is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15322335/10251345). But I tried that way and still got the error. Could I get an explanation of those error messages? Because, if the compiler actually modifies those function signatures to contain `*this` then that should have worked, isn't it?

Comment: `getVar()` doesn't accept any parameters so that's why those 2 calls don't work. Conceptually, you're already passing "this" by using `obj.` which is the instance used to execute the member function.

Comment: please include the full error message (and the non-working code)

Comment: @idclev463035818 The non-working code is the commented-out lines. If I uncommented all of them together, the error messages are pretty long and says things like multicharacter constants, etc. lol

Comment: `this` is a keyword. You cannot name a variable like that. But you could write for example `int getVar(MyClass* theOtherThis)` and it would work. You would have access to `this` and `theOtherThis` inside `getVar()`, both equal. The question is: why do you want to do such thing?

Comment: @Yksisarvinen Simply testing the features of C++, I wanted to know if I could unravel what the compiler is doing for me.

Comment: @ArdentCoder that "hidden parameter" is an implementation detail. Theoretically a compiler could use a completely different technique as long as the result is the same.

Comment: @idclev463035818 Thanks, cmaster helped elaborate this point :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Are only compilers allowed to do this?

Precisely. That's why it's called hidden: It's something that the compiler does on your behalf, but which is hidden from the C++ code that uses it.

The compiler must pass the `this` pointer to the member function somehow, but it does not need to tell you how it does it. It **could** compile the code to the equivalent of `MyClass::getVar(&obj)`, passing the `this` pointer in the same way that it would pass the argument for the C function `free(foo)`. Or it might use a different mechanism that is totally incompatible with non-member argument passing. What it does under the hood is defined by the platform's Abstract Binary Interface standard (ABI), which is not part of the C++ language standard. What happens under Windows could be vastly different from what happens under Linux, and Linux on ARM could be different from Linux on X86, etc.

That said, you can take a look at what actually happens by telling your compiler to produce the assembly code. For `gcc`, the incantation would be

```
g++ -S -Os interestingCode.cpp
```

This will produce a `.s` file that contains how `g++` actually translated your code.

Answer (score 2):

`obj.getVar(&obj)`

This version cannot compile because the `getVar()` member function is not declared to take any parameters.

`MyClass::getVar(&obj)`

This version is using the syntax to access a `static` function but `getVar()` is not `static`, nor does it accept any parameters.

**Note:** The `obj.getVar()` call works because it is specifying which object instance to use (i.e., the `obj.` part) to execute the member function and is conceptually how the member function is *passed the `this` pointer*.

Comment: But the compiler puts a `*this` automatically... So, how could a function call mismatch happen? I'm sorry if this is pretty naive.

Comment: @ArdentCoder It's a mismatch because *you* didn't provide a function with that signature and therefore that function doesn't exist.

Comment: Yes, I knew that but I thought that the compiler was generating that function signature for me :P

Answer (score 1):

When you are doing **obj.getVar()** it is already explicitly specified the pointer **this=&obj** and passed implicitly to getVar. It is not hidden. It is explicitly passed leftside of the function. You can use obj.getVar() or ptrObj->getVar() but in C++ is not allowed to use such construction getVar(thisptr). Hidden means the variable named **this** is nowhere declared, but you can use inside the function.