# Why I am able to call a receiver function which don't have an argument with an argument in go?

Tags: go

```
type Num []int

type Number interface{
    gimmeNum() int
}

func (n Num) gimmeNum() int { 
    if len(n) == 0{
        return -1
    }
    return n[0]
}

func main(){
    nums := Num{1, 2, 3}
    n := Number.gimmeNum(nums) // how is this possible?
    fmt.Println(n)
}
```

In the above code, function, gimmeNum() don't have any parameters to accept, but as seen in the main function I am able to call this function with an argument and working as expected! How is go allowing this?!

Comment: Are you familiar with how most OOP programming languages implement instance vs. noninstance (static) methods? If not, then you need to learn about _the hidden `this` parameter_: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15322268/c-this-pointer-hidden-argument-in-function-calls - except in Go, it isn't always hidden and it allows you to pass your own `this` ("receiver") parameter when you use the "static"-like call-site syntax as you are.

Comment: Right.  That is exactly the same as writing `nums.gimmeNum()`.

Comment: @Dai Thanks for the replay, is there any cases  where we need to use as Number.gimmeNum(nums)?

Comment: @ManuelAntony I don't know (I haven't used Go since 2018), but I imagine it depends entirely on your project and coding style guidelines.

Comment: @ManuelAntony that's called a [method expression](https://go.dev/ref/spec#Method_expressions): *"If `M` is in the method set of type `T`, `T.M` is a function that is callable as a regular function with the same arguments as `M` __prefixed by an additional argument that is the receiver of the method__."*

Comment: @mkopriva, That was helpful, thanks.